# Do floaters reappear later in the game?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I have made a bad mistake and I think Im stuck.

I did not notice that i need floater corpses for the interceptor upgrades.
I sold all corpses on grey market and then only heavy floaters starter appearing.

Funny thing is that the game requires floater corpses and not heavy floater corpses (i mean what...). Am i stuck or what?

With best regards,
no9

Comment: Similar question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109443/can-you-encounter-lower-tier-aliens-in-the-late-game/ (not sure if this counts as a dupe?)

Comment: To quickly answer the question: Floaters do appear in late game, but rarely. I wouldn't want to have to wait for them before progressing...

Comment: Even when you don't encounter any more floaters you would not be stuck. You will just be unable to build defense matrices which are one-use items to reduce the hit chance of an UFO vs. an interceptor for a few seconds. But these are not necessary at all to complete the game. I finished the game without using a single one, due to the "[too awesome to use](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TooAwesomeToUse)" syndrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do still sometimes occur -- mostly in the smaller scout ships where (presumably) heavy floaters would be too expensive an investment for the ship's mission purposes. Just nowhere near as often, and generally not in any situation where the aliens anticipated needing firepower.